# Translating "temperature range" to French

Tags: traduction

What is the common translation for "temperature range" in French?
I am trying to learn about the minimum and maximum temperatures where something can fluctuate between.

These all sound a bit odd or formal:

- plage de température - works more for plages horaires
- portée de la température - sounds more like temperature scope
- fourchette de température - rarely heard this one

Comment: What is the context ? Would "gamme de température" be an option ?

Comment: Météo: (des) Températures entre 28 et 35 degrés. I would leave out range in most cases.

Comment: I agree with Lambie. No need to specify a traduction of "range" for the usual weather forecast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Range is defined here to be either of these definitions from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/range):

> 1. the limits within which a person or thing can function effectively: the range of vision
> 2. the limits within which any fluctuation takes place: a range of values

The best translation imho is:

> - [*Plage de température*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plage_de_temp%C3%A9rature) (*d'utilisation / de fonctionnement / supportée / recommandée*)

It is commonly used, neither too formal or odd.

Then:

> - *Fourchette de température*

is less used but still correct. Often found in statistics, especially about polls.

> - *Portée de température*

doesn't work here. It would for "range of a weapon" → *portée d'une arme*.

Wikipedia suggests *zone de température*, I would use it with something else appended, e.g. *zone de température acceptable/interdite/utilisée*.

About other suggestions by Random and Frank:

> - *Gamme de température*

is rarer but fine. More often used in arts (music, colors) and commerce (*gamme de produits*).

> - *Intervalle de température*

might be used too although in French, *intervalle* is generally representing the difference between the highest and the lowest values, i.e. [the **span** and not the **range**](http://engineersinterview.com/question/difference-between-span-and-range/).

TLFi definition of *intervalle*:

> A. − [Dans l'espace]
>   1. **Distance** qui sépare un lieu, un point, un objet d'un autre; p. méton. espace vide ainsi déterminé. Synon. **écart**, **espace**.
>   ...
>   B. − [Dans le temps] **Distance** qui sépare une époque, une date, un événement d'un(e) autre; p. méton. laps de temps ainsi déterminé. Synon. **écart**, **moment**, **période**.
>
> − MATH., STAT. Ensemble de nombres compris entre deux valeurs. Il peut se trouver indiqué de n'avoir pas **un intervalle constant** dans la constitution des classes. C'est en particulier le cas de la pyramide des âges, classiquement établie **de cinq ans en cinq ans**. Cet intervalle ne convient pas au groupe de la première enfance, parce qu'il ne fait pas ressortir les conséquences de la mortalité infantile (P. Pèpe, Présentation des statistiques, Paris, Dunod, 1959, p. 94).
>   ♦ Intervalle de variation. ,,Appelé aussi **étendue** ou **amplitude**, **l'intervalle de variation est la différence entre deux valeurs extrêmes étudiées**`` (P. Pèpe, Présentation des statistiques, Paris, Dunod, 1959, p. 56).

[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/intervalle/43882?q=intervalle#43806):

Intervalle: **Distance plus ou moins grande entre deux choses, entre un point et un autre : Planter des arbres à intervalles réguliers**.
Read more at http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/intervalle/43882#Rhklm6cKhAEVMFvJ.99

Only in mathematics *[intervalle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalle_(math%C3%A9matiques))* is representing the full range of values but this might not be understood that way by an average reader.

Wikipedia:

> En mathématiques, un intervalle (du latin intervallum) est étymologiquement un ensemble compris entre deux valeurs.

Comment: en maths, un intervalle [a,b] de e.g. R, comprend tous les nombres entre a et b, inclus. Que voulez-vous dire par _différence_ ici?

Comment: @Frank En français, un intervalle représente typiquement une distance, une durée, etc. C'est à dire une valeur unique, pas deux valeurs (min et max). C'est exactement la différence entre *span* et *range* en anglais. On parle d'un intervalle de cinq minutes, un intervalle de deux mètres entre chaque poteau, un intervalle de 10 degrés, etc. Il est vrai que par extension, on peut préciser les valeurs extrêmes mais ce n'est pas l'usage majoritaire. « Intervalle de température » est ambigu si on ne précise pas ces deux valeurs. « Plage de température » indique clairement de quoi il s'agit.

Comment: en français, en maths, et par extension en sciences, un intervalle contient toutes les valeurs intermédiaires, par définition. Ce n'est pas une "extension", c'est la définition mathématique d'un "intervalle".

Comment: Je downvote pour imprécision sur les usages du mot _intervalle_ en français, et en particulier omission de la définition scientifique du terme, ce qui peut être important dans le contexte de la mesure d'une température, par exemple si l'OP a besoin d'une traduction pour un texte scientifique.

Comment: C'est mieux :-) "Intervalle de variation" pourrait être le plus approprié pour le contexte de l'OP. _span_ and _range_ ne sont pas aussi clairement définis que vous l'impliquez en anglais non plus, et vous avez peut-être en fait même intervertis les deux termes, fyi.

Comment: J'upvote de nouveau, mais la réponse est contredite à certains endroits par sapienz en physique, par exemple, ou bien quand TLFi cite les statistiques puis la réponse affirme que seules les maths pures utilisent une certaine définition du mot _intervalle_.

Comment: @Frank Dans l'extrait du BIPM cité par Sapienz, je comprends *intervalle* comme désignant la différence, pas la plage. Seule la différence n'est pas affectée par le changement d'unité (Celsius ←→ kelvin), la plage l'est forcément. De plus la plage a deux valeurs mais le texte parle d'une seule valeur. Ce n'est donc pas le meilleur exemple.

Comment: On lit: _ainsi la valeur numérique d'une différence de température ou d'un intervalle de température est identique quand elle est exprimée en degrés Celsius ou en kelvins._. Il y a donc **deux** choses: _une différence de température_ et _un intervalle de température_, puisque le texte éprouve la nécessité de citer les deux. Ce qui n'est pas très clair, en fait.

Comment: @Frank Une chose ou deux choses car *ou* peut simplement indiquer un nom alternatif, mais de toute façon, le texte parle de **la** valeur numérique. C'est donc très clairement le delta.

Comment: Oui - comme je l'ai dit, ce n'est pas très clair pour distinguer intervalle et différence.

Comment: @Frank Lien ajouté pour span et range, « intervalle de variation » est clairement défini dans le TLFi comme correspondant au *span* (max-min) et pas le *range* (min <= x <= max).

Comment: Dans des dictionnaires anglais, j'ai trouvé "span" défini comme "range" et vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

You might also be able to use:

> intervalle de température

But, an *intervalle* in maths/science in French contains all the values between the minimum and maximum. Just something to be aware of in scientific contexts, depending on what you want to convey.

Comment: That's the English spelling though. Here in France, we write it *intervalle*…

Comment: "intervalle de température" is the most used expression in physics.

Comment: @Frank En métrologie et d'après [le Bureau Internationnal des Poids et Mesures BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/metrologie/thermometry/units.html) c'est bien "intervalle de température" qui est utilisé: Le degré Celsius et le kelvin ont la même taille, ainsi la valeur numérique d'une différence de température ou d'un intervalle de température est identique quand elle est exprimée en degrés Celsius ou en kelvins.